# Stop Execution of Code After Error thrown in Async Await function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, error-handling

I am creating a Nodejs and express based backend application and trying to handle error in a manner which is suitable for production systems.

I use async await to handle all synchronous operations in the code.

Here is a code snippet of router end points

```
app.get("/demo",async (req, res, next) => {
 await helper().catch(e => return next(e))
 console.log("After helper is called")
 res.json(1)
})

function helper(){ //helper function that throws an exception
 return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> reject(new Error("Demo Error")))
}
```

After all routes are defined I have added a common error handler that catches exceptions. To simplify it I am adding a simple function

```
routes.use( (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("missed all", err)

 return res.status(500).json({error:err.name, message: err.message});
});
```

I expect that the code after await helper() should not execute since the exception has been handled and response sent to frontend. Instead what I get is this error.

```
After helper is called
(node:46) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error 
[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the 
client
```

What is the correct way to handle error with async await?

Comment: You can have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685872/how-to-properly-implement-error-handling-in-async-await-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `After helper is called`, because your code continues to `execute` since it did not `return`

Don't chain `catch` with `async/await`. You do that with `Promise`.

```
helper()
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

You can handle error like:

```
app.get("/demo",async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await helper();
    // respond sent if all went well
    res.json(something)
  catch(e) {
    // don't need to respond as you're doing that with catch all error handler
    next(e)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `try` `catch` to handle the situation

```js
app.get("/demo",async (req, res, next) => {
 try {
  await helper()
  console.log("After helper is called")
  res.json(1)
 } catch(err) {
  next(err)
 }
})

function helper(){ //helper function that throws an exception
 return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> reject(new Error("Demo Error")))
}
```